# Error while trying to build flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build, apk

I am facing problems with the build of my apps(the old ones are working but all my new projects are receiving this message)
i already tried rebooting my pc and reinstalling flutter, but this doesn't change the error, and i can't find the solution anywhere

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
'D:\projects\CalendarProject' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

this projects\CalendarProject is a old project, but every project i try to build i receive this message pointing to D:\projects\CalendarProject

also my flutter doctor seems perfectly fine

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.20.4 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (4 days ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\android\AndroidVirtual
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\android\AndroidVirtual
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Users\Joâo Pedro\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[√] VS Code (version 1.49.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Joâo Pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
```

I think it is a config in android folder that is generating this error, but can't imagine what could it be

Comment: If it can help you: https://medium.com/@nabil6391/solutions-to-flutter-error-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-1d2c36b2001a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

the folder that i was using to create projects was inside a folder called "D:\projects\CalendarProject(V3)" (exemple:D:\projects\CalendarProject(V3)\flutter_app)
, don't know is it is a android sdk or flutter bug, but apperently one of them thought CalendarProject(V3) was a function and was trying to run it. this explains the message

```
'D:\projects\CalendarProject' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Fixed by changing the directory

you can recreate the error with:

```
>>mkdir teste(v3)
>>cd "teste(v3)"
>>flutter create app
>>cd app
>>flutter build apk
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using flutter in android studio? if so, try opening the project in "vs code", there seems to be a problem with flutter in android studio...